# C# EPPlus create many tabs causes a null reference exception

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I found a strange error with generating an Excel file using EPPlus library. The scenario is simple - I need to have many worksheets in a single excel file. But, when invoking the `GetAsByteArray()` method, I get the `null reference exception`

```
using (ExcelPackage xml = new ExcelPackage())
{
    foreach (var mainValueItem in values)
    {
        using (ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xml.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"sheet {mainValueItem.ID}"))
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Date";
        }
    }
    return ctr.File(xml.GetAsByteArray(), MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

I can see in both Worksheets, the Cells property is not loaded as you can see here:
[image]

so, how to create many worksheets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer - we shouldn't use

```
using (ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xml.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"sheet {mainValueItem.ID}"))
```

in that scenario. instead, just declare a variable

```
var worksheet = xml.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($"sheet {mainValueItem.ID}");
```

and now it works, I can see multiple tabs in the generated file.

Happy coding !

Comment: Also consider `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` as mime type ;)

Comment: Not can test right now, but returning your File in your second using might be better, if that works.